# Changing Teams in Civ 5

Tags: civilization-5

What is the effect of changing an opponents team in the Advanced Setup screen?

[image]

What benefits do I get from changing the second player to Team 1? Does it give me a permanent ally throughout the game? Can this be used to more effectively beat the games harder AI opponents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being on the same team as another player achieves the following:

- Permanent ally throughout the game. There is no way to break your alliance.
- You are unable to attack the opposing player.
- You share technology and research points.
- Shared vision
- If one of you wins, you both win.
- Shared diplomacy with other civilizations and city states (i.e. if one of you is friendly with a civilization you both are).

One additional thing I'd like to note that is if you are playing in an online multiplayer game and one of the players is wiped out, they are kicked out of the game whether or not any of their allies are still alive.

Comment: they need to make it you can upgrade your units in team-members borders