# How does science in teams work in Civilization V?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

Was playing team based game with my brother against the AI and noticed that the number of turns to research something dropped when we both selected to research the same technology. How does this work? Does it combine all players in the team researching the same technology (ie. its addictive)? or there diminishing returns? and if so what is the formula.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54095/changing-teams-in-civ-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The research in Civ5 is additive. So if both you and your brother is at the same level the turn needed for a research should be split in half.